# run a job on all slaves of same label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have jobs that need to be run on all slaves of the same label. For that I am trying to use configuration matrix.

- Selecting the label only makes jenkins to use on of the slave in the right label.
- Adding the new slave on all my job is just troublesome (many jobs)

So how can I make jenkins to run my jobs on a list of slaves?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a Matrix Configuration job.  It will have a list of all slaves with a checkbox for each one you want it to run on.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to do what you ask for is right now the Groovy Label Assignment plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Label+Assignment+plugin)